# Python: joining multiple lines into a single line/string and appending it to a list

Tags: python, string, list, merge, line

Basically I have a text file, I am reading it line by line. I want to merge some lines together (a part of the text) in to a single string and add it as an element to a list.

These parts of the text that I want to combine start with the letters "gi" and end with ">". I can successfully isolate this part of the text but I am having trouble manipulating with it in any way, i would like it to be a single variable, acting like a individual entity. So far it is only adding single lines to the list.

```
def lines(File):
    dataFile = open(File)
    list =[]
    for letters in dataFile:
        start = letters.find("gi") + 2 
        end = letters.find(">", start)
        unit = letters[start:end]
        list.append(unit)
    return list
```

This is an example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cwv2spfcpp0q0s/pythonmafft.txt?dl=0

So every entry that is in the file I would like to manipulate as a single string and be able to append it to a list. Every entry is seperated by a few empty lines.

Comment: Show an example of what you want to obtain, given your file. You might also want to try Biopython which handles fasta files pretty well.

Comment: I just want it to handle a single sequence as a single string, so it takes up one space in a list, so i can afterward put it in a dictionary, with an appropriate key.  But i just can't get it to act that way, it adds a single line or the whole text.

Comment: you should look at biopython then : http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc49

Comment: This looks really promising, thank you for the info. I'll give it a bash :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use `list` as a variable name. `list` is a builtin and you override it each time you assign the same name elsewhere in your code. Try to use more descriptive names in general and you'll easily avoid this pitfall.

There is an easier way to do what you're asking, since `'>gi'` (in the example you gave) is placed together. You can simply use split and it'll give you the units (without `'>gi'`).

```
def lines(File):
    dataFile = open(File)
    wordlist = dataFile.read().split('>gi')
    return wordlist
```

Comment: Thank you, I was translating the variables from a non-english language, hence the stupid mistake :).

But otherwise I still can't get it to add the amount of text that "wordlist" defines as a single entry in to the list, it just adds the whole text from the file.